# Palindrome checker that ignores non-alphanumeric characters and case Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, palindrome

Need to make a program that checks if a given string is a palindrome, it should work whether the case is different, and should ignore non-alphanumeric characters, only using the ord and chr functions in Data.char and regular functions, nothing else. I was able to create the regular palindrome checker:

```
reverseStr::String->String
reverStr s | s == [] = []
reverseStr (h:t) = reverseStr t ++ [h]

isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome s = s == reverseStr s
```

I've started work on a function to normalize case:

```
normalizeCase::String->String
normalizeCase h | h == [] = []
normalizeCase (h) = if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123
    then map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
    else h
```

But I get these errors:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> Char’
              with actual type ‘Char’
• In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(chr $ (ord h + 32))’
  In the expression: map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
  In the expression:
    if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123 then
        map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
    else
        h

  |
6 |   then map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: Char
• In the expression: h
  In the expression:
    if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123 then
        map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
    else
        h
  In an equation for ‘normalizeCase’:
      normalizeCase [h]
        = if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123 then
              map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
          else
              h
  |
7 |   else h   |        ^
```

I'm still very new to Haskell and have no idea how to implement ord or chr properly so that it works with this checker, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One way is to normalize the case, for example, make all the characters uppercase before checking palindrome.  As a first step, can you figure out how to tell whether a character is lowercase using `ord`?  Play around with the function in `ghci` and see if you can notice a pattern.

Comment: normalizeCase::String->String normalizeCase h | h == [] = [] normalizeCase [h] = if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123 then map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h] else h Gives me errors and not quite sure how to fix.

Comment: _Either_ use `map` to “loop” over the list, or manual-recursive pattern-match deconstruction. (Preferrably `map`.) You seem to be trying to do both simultaneously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
normalizeCase::String->String
normalizeCase h | h == [] = []
normalizeCase (h) = if ord h > 64 && ord h < 123
    then map (chr $ (ord h + 32)) [h]
    else h
```

Your second pattern `(h)` (equivalent to just `h`) matches *any* list (as long as it wasn’t already matched by the first pattern, `h | h == []`); so `h` is a list here and `ord h` doesn’t make sense, since `ord` expects a `Char`, not a `[Char]`.

Assuming `h` was a character, then `chr $ ord h + 32` would also be a character, but `map` expects a *function* as its first argument; this is the source of the error that `Char -> Char` was expected but you gave `Char`. For the second argument to `map`, you pass `[h]`, which is a list of a single element `h` (which in your code is also a list, so you are providing `[[Char]]` when you want `[Char]`).

Also assuming `h` was a character, your condition `ord h > 64 && ord h < 123` matches any character between *uppercase* `A` and *lowercase* `z`, including a few characters you don’t want (`` []^_` ``). The fact that `h` is a *list* of characters is the source of the error that `Char` was expected but you gave `[Char]`.

You also seem to be mixing recursive style with `map`—in this case you should *either* use `map` *or* define the function by cases.

Here’s how your code could look with these errors fixed. First, using recursion:

```
normalizeCase :: String -> String

-- Given an empty list, return an empty list.
-- This happens if the original input was empty,
-- or when we reach the end of the recursion.
normalizeCase [] = []

-- Given a non-empty list,
-- test the first character ‘c’.
normalizeCase (c : cs) = if c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'

  -- If it’s uppercase, lowercase it and
  -- prepend it to the result of normalizing
  -- the remainder of the string ‘cs’.
  then chr (ord c + 32) : normalizeCase cs

  -- Otherwise, don’t change it, but still
  -- prepend it to the result of normalizing
  -- the remainder of the string ‘cs’.
  else c : normalizeCase cs
```

Or, using `map`:

```
normalizeCase :: String -> String

-- Given any string:
normalizeCase s

  -- For each character:
  = map

    -- If it’s uppercase, lowercase it.
    (\ c -> if c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'
      then chr (ord c + 32)
      else c)

    -- Over the whole string.
    s
```

`Char` can be compared directly (`c >= 'A'`), which is more readable, but if you’re expected to use `ord` for the comparison as well, that would be `ord c >= 65`.

I know you’re not supposed to use any other standard functions for this task, but for future reference, this can also be implemented very straightforwardly using `toLower` from `Data.Char`:

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

normalizeCase :: String -> String
normalizeCase s = map toLower s

-- Alternatively, a point-free/eta-reduced version:
normalizeCase = map toLower
```

For the additional task of removing non-alphanumeric characters, you can use `filter`, a list comprehension with a guard condition, or write a direct recursive version yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much, was able to figure out the rest after examining this, really appreciate the help!